# Access Token in React.useEffect generally works, but comes back undefined when page is refreshed / reloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect

I have a simple React page / component in Gatsby that makes an API call. For this API call I need a token. I use [gatsby-theme-auth0](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-auth0/) to obtain this token via their `AuthService` object.

I am starting the API call in my `useEffect`. It looks like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    //defining the async function
    async function fetchFromAPI() {
      try {
        const data = await fetchData()
        setData(data)
      }
    }
    
    //executing the async function:
    fetchFromAPI()
  }, [])
```

The function `fetchData()`, which is asynchronously called in `useEffect` currently looks like so:

```
async function fetchData() {
  
  const client = new GraphQLClient(SERVER_URL_GRAPHQL)
  let aToken = await AuthService.getAccessToken()
  client.setHeader('authorization', `Bearer ${aToken}`)
  const query = ...

  const data = await client.request(query)
  return data
}
```

All of this *generally works*. When I navigate to this page, from a different page within my SPA it works. However, when I reload the page, it doesn't. the access token (`aToken`) then comes back as `undefined`.

**But:** *I can make things work*, when I wrap a `setTimeout` around the whole call. Then the access token comes back fine and isn't `undefined`. So I guess something first needs to initialise before `AuthService` can be called? I'm just not sure how to ensure this.

But this is not what I want to do in production. Now I am wondering why this is. Maybe I am using `useEffect` the wrong way? Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything online or on github so far. I'm sure the problem is rather basic though.

EDIT: The `AuthService.getAccessToken()` method can be found [here](https://github.com/epilande/gatsby-theme-auth0/blob/master/gatsby-theme-auth0/src/auth/service.ts) It's part of `gatsby-theme-auth0`

EDIT: To clarify, the server does receive the request and sends back `{"error":"jwt malformed"}` - which makes sense, since it's `undefined`.

Comment: Have you verified that you get an appropriate response from the server?  Is it just the client-side code that is not working?

Comment: Please include the `getAccessToken` method

Comment: @jack.benson Just the client side code. Everything works fine when I navigate to the page via my SPA, just when I reload the page directly it doesn't.

Comment: @k.s. The getAccess method is provided to me by `gatsby-theme-auth0`. Here you can find the method: https://github.com/epilande/gatsby-theme-auth0/blob/master/gatsby-theme-auth0/src/auth/service.ts I can also include it in the question. AFAIU, it basically just returns a private variable, which is the access Token.

Comment: Have you verified that when you reload the page the network request is submitted and an appropriate and expected response is received?

Comment: @jack.benson yes, the server sends back `{"error":"jwt malformed"}`  (since it's `undefined`)

Comment: I meant the auth token request.  Do you see that?  The value of `aToken`?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding you. The value of aToken is `undefined` and the server receives `authorization: Bearer undefined` - is this what you mean? Sorry if I'm not getting this.

Comment: @R.Kohlisch where is the authentication handled ? in the same component?

Comment: Oh, I see, I was mistaken.  I thought the `getAccessToken` method was a server call.  Based on the linked source code it is not. :)  Have you checked `localStorage` to make sure the data that you are expecting is there?  It looks like it should be there.  Otherwise, you need to call the `handleAuthentication` or `checkSession` method from that library.  Those methods in turn call `setSession`, which sets `this.accessToken`.  That is the value returned from `getAccessToken`, so if it isn't set that library won't work.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have the authentication in a hook already or not, but you need to check if the user is authenticated before you make any api call, especially those that on app init. Do you have a hook/context when you handle the authentication ? If you have, you can change your code a bit

```
 const {isAuthenticated} = useContext(userAuthenticatedContext)

 useEffect(() => {
    //defining the async function
    async function fetchFromAPI() {
      try {
        const data = await fetchData()
        setData(data)
      }
    }
    
    //executing the async function:
    if(isAuthenticated) fetchFromAPI()
  }, [isAuthenticated])
```

This way, `isAuthenticated` is a dependency in your `useEffect` and it will run again when the value of `isAuthenticated` is changed and it will not fail as you are doing a check, before making the call.

Answer (score 0):

`getAccessToken` relies on that modules' `this.accessToken` value to be set.  It looks like you need to call either `handleAuthentication` or `checkSession` prior to making your call so that the value gets initialized properly.  Consider putting `checkSession` somewhere that runs when the page loads.